# M5015 Disk controller - Replace failed disk used working disk

Tags: raid, hard-drive, hardware-raid, raid5

I have an IBM X3200 M3 machine with a M5015 SATA Disk controller (RAID 5). One of the disks has failed ie orange light flashing on the disk.

- I intend to replace the damaged disk with a used disk of the same SN.
  It has redundant old data on it.
- Firstly I intend to run Director to ensure that the firmware is
  updated in the controller.
- Then run the raid utility on boot up to check it is indeed configured to a RAID 5 setup – just been told at this stage (need to be certain).
- Then ensure the system is backed up.
- Then turn off the server and replace the disk– with the other used disk with data on. The array should be rebuilt with the new disk.

Is there anything wrong with this process and is it OK to use a disk that is used with data on ???

Thanks for your input